# How to select the latest set of dated records from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Hi i am storing chat data in one table (not my design) MYSQL!

```
Table: chat
id          (long)
lastWrite   (date) 
messageStatus (varchar) //can be send , received, read
toName(varchar) //receiver
```

My Problem is i dont know how to get a list of only the latest (with latest timestamp of lastWrite) of all the different receivers (only one line per receiver). The Goal should be to Show the latest messageStatus from all receivers in one list.

i tryed:

```
select * from (
    select c.*   from chat c where organizationId = 885 order by c.lastWrite    desc
) as tmp group by tmp.toName
```

It seems the right direction but sth. wrong because it gives me not the latest entry, it gives me only one entry per receiver, thats what i want but it is not the last entry, it seems like its a random one.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you get all the columns  for the latest message for each toName

```
  select * 
  from chat 
  where ( toName, lastwrite) in ( 
      SELECT toName, MAX(lastwrite)
      FROM chat
      GROUP BY toName
```

or if you need  ondlu messageStatus

```
select toName, lastwrite, messageStatus 
from chat 
where ( toName, lastwrite) in ( 
    SELECT toName, MAX(lastwrite)
    FROM chat
    GROUP BY toName
  )
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is the solution. it works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT toName, MAX(lastwrite), messageStatus
FROM chat
GROUP BY toName, messageStatus
```

Comment: This is why code only answers are bad. Explain your solutions please!

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.